# Configure value object with inheritance relationship in EF Core 6 Fluent API

Tags: inheritance, domain-driven-design, value-objects, ef-core-6.0

I am trying to implement DDD in one of my project where I am struggling to configure value object in ef-core 6 fluent api.

My value Object is a abstract type Schedule and it has concrete type such as Daily, Monthly etc.

```
public abstract class Schedule : ValueObject
{
 public DateOnly StartFrom { get; init; }

}

public class Monthly : Schedule
{
  public List<int> DaysOfMonth { get; private set; }
}
```

---

```
// Entity which owns the Value Object :-

public class SubscribedItem : Entity
{
   public Schedule Schedule { get; private set; }
}
```

---

```
public class SubscribedItemEntityTypeConfiguration : 
       IEntityTypeConfiguration<SubscribedItem>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<SubscribedItem> builder)
   {
    builder.OwnsOne(p => p.Schedule, pp =>
    {
        pp.Property(ppp => ppp.StartFrom).IsRequired();
      // How to configure concrete type Monthly value object.
    });
   }
 }
```

How to configure concrete type value object.
i.e. I want in Monthly Schedule Type DaysOfMonth to serialize and de-serialize while saving and retrieving from Database

Answer (score 0):

Use `pp.OwnsOne` in your configuration for the value object navigation property. However, you need also to set up a [value conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions) for the `DaysOfMonth` property